# Multithreading model in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, operating-system

I have been following a course on Operating Systems over the past few months. However, I'd like some clarification on one point that I read. From my understanding, there are three types of multithreading models to map user level threads to kernel level threads -

- Many to one model
- Many to many model
- One to one model

I can see why the many to one model is not very efficient when it comes to parallel processing - because a blocking system call would mean halting of any processing.
However, in the book I'm referring, Operating System Concepts (By Abraham Silberschatz, Greg Gagne and Peter Galvin), it says that both Linux and the Windows family use the one to one model, even though there is the extra overhead of creating a kernel thread for every user thread that's created. 
Wouldn't a many to many model be better? Because you have a number of kernel threads, sufficient to have a high degree of parallelism, and you can always opt for a two level model to bind a user level thread to a kernel level thread.
TLDR: Why is the one to one multithreading model preferred over many to many model despite the overhead in Windows and Linux systems?

Comment: Because in a many to many model you introduce even more overhead. (However some architectures use it, especially with Goroutines or Actors.

Comment: @eckes thanks for the quick reply. Could you elaborate on that a bit more? What exactly introduces more overhead in a many to many model?

Comment: You basically have to implement a task scheduler in software in addition to the one in the OS. This also includes a way to switch execution tasks or context. For Actor models or stack-less software threads I guess the second point is less of a problem.

Comment: On Windows, at least, the overhead is minimal.  The kernel stack only takes up approximately three pages, compared to the default user-mode stack which is 1MB.  About 1.2%, plus I guess a small amount of housekeeping.  And while I'm not an expert, it seems obvious that having only one kind of thread must simplify things enormously, so it is probably a sensible trade-off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't a many to many model be better?

I'd suggest getting another book. AFAIK the Many-to-Many model is entirely theoretical (If someone knows of a system that uses it, please indicate in a comment). These models are a very poor way of explaining threads.

In ye olde days operating system had no concept of threads. They scheduled processes for execution. In fact, this is still the case for many operating systems.

The need for threads was largely driven by the Ada programming language that required "task" support. In order to have a compliant Ada implementation there had to be a library that simulated threads within a single process. In such a system a process schedules its own thread execution ("user threads). This has the drawback that the threads always run interleaved (never in parallel on different processors).

This is being called "many to one" but that is a poor description of what is happening. Your model calls that "many user threads" are being mapped to a single "kernel thread." In reality, there are no kernel threads. Instead threads are being implemented in the context of a process.

It has become common for operating systems to view processes as an address space with multiple schedulable threads of execution. in such a system the thread is the basic unit of scheduling; not the process. Is is the one-to-one model in your scheme.

> it says that both Linux and the Windows family use the one to one model, even though there is the extra overhead of creating a kernel thread for every user thread that's created.

This is kind of BS.There is overhead for a thread no matter how they are implemented. You will often find people claiming that "Many-to-One" is more efficient than "One-to-One." This claim appears to be just urban legend.

> Why is the one to one multithreading model preferred over many to many model despite the overhead in Windows and Linux systems?

The "one-to-one" (aka kernel threads) model is preferable because it takes advantage of multiple processors and allows actual execution in parallel. It also avoids blocking problems that can occur in some systems (e.g. Eunuchs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I'll refer some other book for multithreading then.

Comment: They are making it too complicated for what it is.

Comment: There are some many to many implementations listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Threading_models however indeed all mainstream OS use one to one

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the "many to many" model implies doing the scheduling in user space, so it means that each program must have its own scheduler running in each kernel thread, using it to share that thread between the user threads assigned to it. In other words: you need something like GNU Portable Threads running in each kernel thread to dispatch the user threads assigned to that kernel thread (https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/).